# Laravel 5.6 Redirect to Intended URL after Login not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

On Laravel 5.6 I've been working with Redirect to Intended URL after Login. The business case:

1. I try to go to /article/create, which requires a user to be logged
   in.
2. User is redirected to signup form at /auth/login.
3. User now signs in and is redirected back to their **intended URL**
   at /article/create.

My Code:

For Url Previous I used the following code in LoginController.php and work like a charm

```
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
        return view('auth.login');
    }
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect(session('link'));
    }
```

For Intended URL I tried to Use

`session()->put('url.intended',url()->previous());`

instead of

`session(['link' => url()->previous()]);`

But its not working, Im receiving error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Redirector could not be converted to string

Additionally I tried `redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl();` getTargetUrl does not exist. so Error: Method Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::getTargetUrl does not exist.

Even I tried with redirectTo: but additionally, laravel don't have redirectTo function.

Honestly I dont know how to continue and base on the fact its login area I have some security concerns continuing changing the code.

Despite I read many post at SO no one is defining a functional code to work with intended url with getTargetUrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not properly redirecting the user to the `intended` url, the proper way is to use method called `intended` and pass a `default` route if the `intended` route is not found (if it returns `404`), it's something of a fallback route.

Proper intended redirection can be found in the official docs, but I will give you an example for your implementation:

```
   /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('article/create');
        }
    }
```

The method above resolves even your `previous` url so you can remove saving of `url` inside the `Session`

P.S: Maybe it wasn't clear, but `intended` actually saves the `previous url for you` so you don't have to save it yourself, therefore you can remove your code for `saving previous url`

EDIT: To backup my claims, you can take a look at this [Github perma link](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/004e933a52f8eb78e63f53c7d998e2360bd79e3c/Redirector.php#L98-L112) of the `Laravel Router` repo.

To always forward to the same route you can `define a $redirectTo` attribute on the `LoginController` which will `ALWAYS` redirect users to that `url`.

```
public $redirectTo = '/home';
```

But in order for this to work, you need to `REMOVE` implementation of `authenticated` and `authenticate`

Comment: Probably I dont explain well. My idea is to forward Any intended URL after login, in this case it redirects to ('article/create'). Thats why I tried using something like getTargetUrl()

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl();

        }

Comment: with redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl(); seems to be working, Best Regards!